# Vertical lines on iMac

Tags: imac, performance

I have vertical lines showing up on my 2.16 GHz 2 GB RAM Core 2 Duo iMac. Any idea what's going on and what I need to do to fix it? My computer is also freezing frequently.

Comment: Screenshot or picture?

Answer (score 1):

It could be either a driver issue or a hardware problem. If you are still under AppleCare, I would just take it to a Genius Bar so they can do a diagnosis and see if it's a hardware problem (the easier fix). Otherwise, I'd recommend doing a full backup and installing a fresh copy of OSX.

Comment: A lot of times this is usually a hardware issue.  Usually the screen or the logic board/graphics card.  Make an appointment this a Genius, they do free diagnostic even if you aren't under warranty that way you can at least get help with what may be wrong.